# AMQP . Is it a better way to use JWT over certificate based authentication

Tags: tls, jwt

We are in search of the best possible way to secure our AMQP connection. Our AMQP clients are distributed all around the world and connection to the AMQP server needs to be secure. We are using TLS for the transport level security as recomended by the oasis-open.org . And now looking for the AUTH mechanism for AMQP clients.

One way is to use the same TLS certificate to authenticate the user and **SECOND** way is to use the new famous JWT as auth mechanism for AMQP. Whenever a client is publishing or subscribing to an AMQP queue, it should get auth by the server by sending the JWT to the server.